# Get most recent Price for each Item

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table:

```
ItemID PurchaseDate Price  
001 03/17/2013 19.00  
002 03/17/2013 14.00  
001 03/18/2013 13.00  
002 03/18/2013 15.00  
001 03/19/2013 17.00  
003 03/19/2013 19.00
```

I need to write a `SQL query` to get the `Price` corresponding to the latest `PurchaseDate` for each `ItemID`.
Entries in table might not necessarily be entered ordered by date
Like this:

```
ItemID PurchaseDate Price  
001 03/19/2013 17.00  
002 03/18/2013 15.00  
003 03/19/2013 19.00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea behind the subquery is it separately gets the latest `PurchaseDate` for each `ItemID`. The result of the subquery is then joined back on the table provided that it matches on two conditions: `ItemID` and `PurchaseDate`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ItemID, MAX(PurchaseDate) max_date
            FROM     TableName
            GROUP   BY ItemID
        ) b ON  a.ItemID = b.ItemID AND
                a.PurchaseDate = b.max_date
```

Comment: Why are u so **QUICK** ? **:P**

Comment: @JW No go in Access 2010, unfortunately: "Syntax error in JOIN operation."

Comment: @GordThompson it works in access. just put "TableName AS a" in fist FROM clause and "TableName AS b" in second FROM clause, oh, and "MAX(PurchaseDate) AS max_date".
Gave CHECK to JW because his answer faster, and I used his query. Thanks JW.

Comment: For the record: I submitted an edit to this answer to fix the syntax so it would *actually work* in Access but that edit was apparently rejected.

Answer (score 3):

```
-- WITH clause, works with Oracle.
-- I added this clause to dynamically run the SELECT statement without any DDL.
-- Ignore this section for use on MS Access
WITH v AS (
  SELECT 001 ItemID, TO_DATE('03/17/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') PurchaseDate, 19.00 Price FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 002, TO_DATE('03/17/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 14.00 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 001, TO_DATE('03/18/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 13.00 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 002, TO_DATE('03/18/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 15.00 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 001, TO_DATE('03/19/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 17.00 FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 003, TO_DATE('03/19/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 19.00 FROM dual
)
-- The WITH clause was upto here.
-- Below starts the main query which works on most platforms including MS Access.
-- I have referenced to the same table "v" two times - v_in and v_out.
-- You will need to change the "v" with your table name.
  SELECT v_out.itemid, v_out.purchasedate, v_out.price
    FROM v v_out
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM v v_in
                  WHERE v_in.itemid = v_out.itemid
               GROUP BY v_in.itemid
                 HAVING MAX(v_in.purchasedate) = v_out.purchasedate)
ORDER BY v_out.itemid
;
```

Comment: @JW, common table expression? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx . did you really test your query?

Comment: Yes! MS-ACCESS does allow `EXISTS` queries. Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa217680%28v=office.11%29.aspx . I coded the `WITH` clause just to do all this in one single query and it works in Oracle. Alin I can use the main `SELECT` query as a reference though. The logic is perfect.

Comment: @Rachcha Yes, Access supports EXISTS but not WITH. The main SELECT query does indeed work in Access. You might consider editing your answer to clarify, in which case I will upvote.